# Queryset con 2 campos de una tabla - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, djangorestframework, django-admin

Quiero hacer un filtro con 2 campos del modelo **user** de django
**first_name y last_name**
De esta manera:

```
queryset = User.objects.annotate(search_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name'))
queryset.filter(search_name__icontains='Prueba Pruebita')
```

Pero no me esta devolviendo el filtro si no toda la lista de usuarios.

Este es mi serializer que simplemente trae la mayoría de campos y el password que solo sea de escritura.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'code', 'phone')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

Me esta faltando algo? o hay otra manera de poder hacer un filtro con 2 campos de un modelo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De alguna manera, funciona de esta manera:

```
fullname = request.data.get('full_name', None)
queryset = User.objects.all()
    if fullname:
        queryset = queryset.annotate(search_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name'))
        queryset = queryset.filter(search_name__icontains=names)
```

Espero le sirva a alguien. :)